# Making javascript pop up middle of the screen instead of middle of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js pop up that pops up in the middle of my page. Problem is, when user scroll down to the bottom of the page and click the button to trigger the pop up, the pop up will appear at the top instead of middle of the screen (because the user had already scroll down, so he/she isn't at the middle of the page already).

What I want is, no matter where are the user is viewing, the pop up will be at the middle of the user's SCREEN.

```
function centerPopup(){
var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var popupHeight = $(".popupContent").height();
var popupWidth = $(".popupContent").width();
$(".popupContent").css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
    "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
});
//this is needed for ie6
$(".backgroundPopup").css({ "height": windowHeight });
}
```

Or is it possible to have a pop up below the button that trigger the pop up?

Comment: just disable/enable the scrollig , when popup is displayed

Comment: Use `position: fixed` instead.

Comment: I see, thanks bro. Would it be nuisance for a user that use touch screen device when they zoom in? Do you have some sample code for jQuery that pop ups directly below the button?

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it ,but there is a possibility it will work

```
function centerPopup(){

var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var popupHeight = $(".popupContent").outerHeight();
var popupWidth = $(".popupContent").outerWidth();
var windowScrollTop =  $(window).scrollTop();
var windowScrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();

$(".popupContent").css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": Math.max(0,((windowHeight -popupHeight) /2)+windowScrollTop) + "px",
    "left": Math.max(0,((windowWidth -popupWidth) /2)+windowScrollLeft) + "px"
});

}
```